# WinBUGs giving 'Illegal memory write error' running under wine

Tags: r, spatial-statistics

Ok some I am trying to use Winbugs to do spatial smoothing. I am running r code in R study and using `R2WinBUGS` to call Wine 1.4 under Mac OSx Mountain Lion. It works ok for some models but for the CAR model I have set up Winbugs seems to run just fine until the very end when I am getting a Quartz X11 Blackbox error -I took a screen grab of the error box [image: Quartz error box]

I cannot figure out what is causing this or how to fix it. Anyone come across this before ?

Comment: I've set up R and winbugs in my windows & partition and running under this environment generates a Trap error in Winbugs. Therefore I do not think it is Wine but a Winbugs trap error. However I have no idea how to diagnose and fix this. I am trying to implement a modification of Besag-York-Mollie model in fig 11.11 of Applied Spatial Data Analysis with R

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about installation of R, which isn't a GIS specific question.

Comment: How is it about installation of R ?!? R is installed fine and I am not asking about that. I'm asking about doing spatial smoothing using winbugs through R which is absolutely a GIS question

Comment: On second though, and with reading your comment, I realize I was mistaken. I have nominated it for reopening. I would humbly suggest that you provide more information about the issue, indicating what you have tried to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid WinBUGS (and so-called OpenBUGS) entirely. Running under Wine is a double not-good. I wrote a justification of this position: http://geospaced.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/why-you-should-not-use-winbugs-or.html

You might be able to fit your model with functions from the [CARbayes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CARBayes/index.html) package. That will run natively in Linux. There are other spatial bayesian packages, check out CRAN and the Spatial Task View.

Comment: hi Spacedman - yeah I suspect Wine is the main problem. This set up was workign fine for me -its jsut throw this error if I run large simulation and when I changed my model.
I _think_ Wine is doing naughty things with memory management - but its beyond my skills to fix or even figure out exactly the problem.

Yeah I'm aware of CARbayes and may look at it but not giving up on BUGS just yet.

Comment: Spacedman - I like your article! Its not 100% up to me however I will have play with CARBayes as I am getting very tired chasing these errors